# How to Update DataGridView dynamically in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview

I am extremely sorry if a duplicate/similar question exists.

I have two forms: Result who's output is just a DataGridView and Main_Form which computes values for the Result form. The input is via a 'folder' which has various files which, after undergoing some computation, generate some values. These values are supposed to be put in the DataGridView.

**My problem is that the 'folder' had those files being generated dynamically via some other application. How to I update my DataGridView without creating a new instance of the Result form?**

I am creating a new instance of the Result form, so currently my code looks like this. I would break the infinite loop with after a particular period of time has lapsed...say 20 minutes.

```
while(true)
{
   FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
   if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any())
   {
       System.IO.DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
       FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.*");
       foreach (FileInfo f in Files)
       {
           if (IsFileLocked(f)) // since files are generated run-time
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // wait                         
           // code that computes values for currently f existing files
           frm = new Result(parameters);
           frm.Show();
   }
   else
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is knowing when to update the `DataGridView`? If you are getting the data from files you can use [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect file changes and update the `DataGridView`. I do not see the form code so you if you want to refresh the grid without creating a new instance you will need to detect the changes in the `Result` form and update there.